# A rational function integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate :
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{a-1}}}{1+{{x}^{b}}}}\text{d}x,\ \ \ a,\ b\in {{\mathbb{N}}^{+}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac1{1+x^b} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k x^{bk}$$
Hence,
$$I(a,b) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k x^{a+bk-1} dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{a+bk} = \dfrac{\Phi(-1,1,a/b)}b$$
where $\Phi(z,s,a)$ is the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) function.
If $a=b$, we get
$$I(a,a) = \dfrac{\log 2}a$$

Answer (score 4):

I'm lazy and would just use a Taylor series since it's easy to compute from the geometric series formula.

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b} \, dx
&= \int_0^1 x^{a-1} \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{bn} \right)\, dx
\\&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 (-1)^n x^{a-1+bn} \, dx
\\&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{a+bn}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple: $${\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,{\frac {a}{b}};\,{\frac {a+b}{b}};\,-1)}{a}^{-1}$$